# Where does the infinitive 'fieri' come from?

Tags: morphology, conjugation, irregular-words

What is the origin of the infinitive *fieri*?
It is unusual in many respects.
The stem seems to be *fi-* and the infinitive ending *-eri* is only found in the second conjugation.
However, the second conjugation has a long *e* and *fieri* seems to follow the third rather than the second conjugation.

The best explanation I can think of is that it was originally *fiere*.
The present stem conjugation of *fieri* is morphologically active (although semantically passive if you see it as passive of *facere*), so the active infinitive ending *-ere* would make sense.
If the form was later passivized, one would expect *fii* or perhaps even *fi* according to the third conjugation, but by analogy to conjugations 1, 2, and 4 the change *-re > -ri* makes sense.
This is only a guess on my part, as convincing analogies are hard to find.

So, what do we know about the origin of the infinitive *fieri*?
Are there any attested alternative or earlier forms of the infinitive *fieri* that could shed light on its history?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any solid information on the etymology of the Latin infinitive, which is frustrating. I'm sure it's out there, so this will be only a partial answer (containing a decent helping of speculation) for now.

But one thing seems fairly clear: PIE didn't have an infinitive per se. Different language groups developed it independently post-PIE. In Italic in particular, a verbal noun with the suffix *-si* developed: **dōnā-* "give" → **dōnāsi* "to give". In Latin, this developed into the active and passive infinitives *dōnāre* and *dōnārī* through rhotacism (and presumably an extra suffix on the passive, though I can't find any details on this part—but final short **i* > *e* is regular).

In what became the third and fourth conjugations, there were three different types of verbs: the consonant-stem thematic verbs, the **i*-stem thematic verbs, and the **y*-suffix verbs. The first of these had infinitives like **edesi* (from **ed-* "eat"), the second had infinitives like **θakiesi* (from **θaki-* "make"), and the last had infinitives like **gwenyesi* (from **gweny-* "come").

But the verb that would become *fiō* was special. Its stem was originally **fui-* from PIE **bʰuH-* "become, come into being", and this led to an infinitive **fuiesi*.

Latin didn't like having sequences of short vowels together. So the **u* ended up disappearing from the present forms (but not the perfect, which became Latin *fuī*). But this stopped the ending **-iesi* from contracting into * *-esi*, which happened in the other third-conjugation i-stems (* *θakiesi* > * *θakesi* > *facere*). The vowel deletion only applied once, and since it deleted the *u*, it never went back and deleted the *i*.

This left infinitives **fiesi* > **fiere, fierī*, with an extra *i* before the ending. And this *i* then prevented the passive from contracting into **fiī* as happened in the rest of the third conjugation.

So *fierī* looks special simply because of an accident: it had an extra vowel that later disappeared. As for why it uses only the passive infinitive, I really can't say ("it's semi-deponent" is a cop-out).

Comment: +1 Is it possible that the *fiere* forms eventually became passive because, semantically, they would fit into the paradigm of *facere* in a passive role? I don't know about classical Latin, but in school we learned that the perfect of *fieri* was *factum esse*, which means (amongst other things) "to have been made"—and which is identical in form and sense to the passive of *facere*. So if *fiere* means the same thing as *faceri*, then one of the two is redundant, so they can be merged/suppleted. And then *fieri* will get the *-i* befitting its passive role in the new paradigm. Or something.

Comment: @Cerberus I honestly have no idea, but it seems plausible! The suppletion is a good point but I don't know how much evidence we have of the details

Comment: Neither do I! Just speculating omnibus visuris et audituris...