# Where did the passive infinitive come from?

Tags: etymology, verbs, vowel, infinitive

The etymology of the present active infinitive seems well-documented. Proto-Italic had an infinitive-like suffix **-si*, so **dōnā-* + **-si* = **dōnāsi* > *dōnāre* by regular sound changes (*s* → *z* → *r* between vowels, and all short vowels → *e* word-finally).

But where did the passive infinitive come from? It looks like the active infinitive with some sort of suffix added, but where would such a suffix come from? Why does it look different in the third conjugation? And for that matter, where did **-si* come from in the first place? It doesn't seem to line up with anything from PIE.

This came up while investigating [the infinitive of *fierī*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6460/406).

Comment: The active infinitive is uniform (*-re*) across the regular Latin conjugations, but the passive one isn't: the third conjugation loses the consonant. Are you looking for an explanation of this too? Or any explanation of the origins of the long *-i*? (I never understood why it's *trahi* instead of *traheri*. Perhaps that needs to be asked at some point, too.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Good points! Added that to the question.

Comment: Remember that historically infinitives are case forms of verbal nouns, so the active infinitive suffix *se could be locative, whereas **the passive infinitive marker ī could be dative** (at least, that's what Meiser or Weiss say).

Comment: @AlexB. Interesting! Do they speculate as to where those suffixes came from? Regardless, that would be a good answer.

Comment: It seems to me the idea that *se is the fossilized locative singular of a neuter s-stem has been around and accepted for at least sixty years, if not more (e.g. Tronskii 1960). With the passive marker, it is perhaps less clear - I'll try to write an answer tomorrow.

Comment: I asked a separate [question about the third conjugation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6634/79). It might be better to also split off other subquestions, as there are no answers to this somewhat broad (but interesting!) question so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Vine's "The Morphology of Italic", all the infinitive endings **originated with the third/consonant conjugation**, and were extrapolated from there.

Many consonant-stem verbs in Latin used to share a root with an S-stem noun: in other words, the verb was formed by putting (thematic) verb endings directly on the PIE root, and the noun was formed with an extra *-s* before the noun endings.

For example, the Old Latin verb *gen-ō* "give birth to" shares its root with the S-stem *gen-os-s, gen-os-is* "birth" (later *genus, generis*). The locative singular of this noun was *gen-es-i* "in birth", which became ***gen-er-e* "to give birth to"** by regular sound change.

Over time, this got re-analyzed as *gene-se*: in other words, a suffix *-se* attached to the present stem of a verb. And since it was really useful having an infinitive form, this was extrapolated to all the other conjugations, as well as other forms that didn't have S-stem nouns in the first place: *habu-is-**se*** "to have held", *es-**se*** "to be".

*(The alternation between S and R is due to rhotacism: sometime in the Old Latin period, S between vowels turned into Z, then into R. This is why habē-re has an R in the suffix while es-se has an S.)

Other Italic languages, though, formed their infinitives somewhat differently—and it's likely that pre-Old-Latin followed some of these patterns too. The passive was never quite as common, so it took longer to settle down and never got fully regularized.

- The oldest infinitive pattern, with cognates in Indo-Iranian languages, goes back to a PIE suffix like **-dʰyēi*. In Italic this became **-ðjē*, which we see in words like Umbrian *pihafei* (on the Iguvine Tablets—stem cognate with Latin *piāre*).

  - In Oscan, an extra passive *-r* was stuck on the end, the same one seen in most other passive endings (*-or*, *-tur*, *-ntur*, etc). This formed the passive infinitive *sacrafīr* (stem cognate with Latin *sacrificāre*).
  - Latin did the same thing, but turned the **ð* into a *z* between vowels and deleted it after consonants. So the "original" Latin passive infinitive was *-ier* as in *ag-(z)ier*, *amā-(z)ier*, etc, which led to the archaic-but-Classically-attested forms like ***agier, amārier***: these used to be far and away the most popular infinitives in the third conjugation.
- Another option came from *root* nouns in the third conjugations, where noun endings were stuck on the PIE root with no adulteration: instead of *gen-os-s*, the root noun would be simply *gen-s*. Root nouns were never very prominent in Italic, but Vedic used the dative singular of root nouns as a passive infinitive.

  - And in fact, the dative singular of a root noun in Latin would look like ***ag-ī* "to be driven"** (< **ag-ej* "to/for driving"), which is exactly what we see in the third conjugation!
  - Once the *-rier* passive infinitive fell out of fashion, this is the formation that stuck in the third conjugation. But it never spread to the other conjugations, which didn't have root nouns to work with.
- Yet another option was to use the dative singular, but from the S-stem noun instead of the root noun. This ending would be **-s-ej*, becoming Latin *-s-ī*, and this was quickly applied to the first, second, and fourth conjugations. It looked a lot like the *-se* active infinitive so it was easy to remember and that was a big advantage. Hence, forms like ***amārī* "to be loved"**.

  - But, this new form never managed to displace the root-noun *-ī* infinitive in the consonant conjugation, which stuck around and gave us the unexpected third-conjugation forms.