# When did the infinitive in -ier fall out of use?

Tags: language-evolution, morphology, passive-voice, infinitive, old-latin

[At one point](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/10693/406), the Latin passive infinitive was formed with a suffix *-(r)ier*, as in *agier* "to be driven", *amārier* "to be loved".

Allen and Greenough call this an "ancient form[…] found chiefly in poetry", but it is indeed well-attested poetically: it shows up in Vergil, Ovid, Lucretius, Naevius, and others, as well as the older Latin of Plautus.

Do we know when this transition happened: when *-(r)ier* became archaic and poetic, and *-(r)ī* took over? To put it another way, if I went back in time to Ancient Rome, at what point would I not sound pretentious saying *agier* and *amārier* in place of *agī* and *amārī*?