# The active and passive infinitives are said to be from locative and dative nouns, respectively: why?

Tags: phonology, infinitive, passive-voice, dative, locative

According to [this post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6463/where-did-the-passive-infinitive-come-from/10693#10693), the active infinitive was formed as the locative of nouns based on verbal stems. Why was the locative used for the infinitive, rather than, say, the accusative?

The noun *genos/genus* "birth" had a locative like *genesi/genere* or similar, "in birth": I wonder what the semantic conexion and development was from there to an infinitive "being born".

The same applies to the dative ending -i turning a similar noun into a passive infinitive, although it seems this reconstruction is somewhat less widely accepted. What does the dative case have to do with (infinite) passivity?